# Taking attendance of guests and students using mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to track the attendance of students and guests using `PHP` and `MySQL`.

I have three tables: students, guests, and attendance.

> Students: student_id | first_name | last_name | grade
>
> Guests: guest_id | first_name | last_name | grade
>
> Attendance: id | attended | student_id | guest_id

The student_id and guest_id in the attendance table are foreign keys referencing the guest_id and student_id in the guests and students tables respectively..

The webpage displays a form that lists the students and guests with a checkbox next to each name. When the form is submitted the $_POST data will contain the students and guests that are present.

I want to populate the guest_id or student_id foreign key fields depending on if the person is a student or a guest. When I submit the form the `$_POST` data comes in the form

> $_POST['guest{guest_id}'] = guest_id and
>   $_POST['student{student_id}']=student_id
>
> **Ex. $_POST['student11'] = 11 and $_POST['guest52'] = 52**

. How can I take this post data and determine if the entry is a guest or a student?

My form code is:

```
<form class="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2"></th>
                <th class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">Name</th>
                <th col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2>Grade</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td><strong>---Students---</strong></td><td></td>
            </tr>

            <?php

            if( mysqli_num_rows($studentResult) > 0 ) {
                while( $row = $studentResult->fetch_assoc() ) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . '<input type="checkbox" name="student' . $row['id'] . '"' . 'value="' . $row['id'] . '">';
                    echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['grade'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            } else { // if no entries
                echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>You have no students!</div>";
            }

            ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td><td><strong>---Guests---</strong></td><td></td>
            </tr>
            <?php

            if( mysqli_num_rows($guestResult) > 0 ) {
                while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($guestResult) ) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . '<input type="checkbox" name="guest' . $row['id'] . '"' . 'value="' . $row['id'] . '">';
                    echo "<td>" . $row['first_name'] . " " . $row['last_name'] . "</td><td>" . $row['grade'] . "</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }
            mysqli_close($conn);
            ?>
        </table>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>    
    </form>
```

Comment: Seems a bit broad. Can we narrow it down a bit?

Comment: @tcadidot0 Presumably, the downvoters would only be repeating what I've already said. Database developers tend to shun redundancy.

Comment: I edited the description so I hope that it clarifies what I am asking for help on.

Comment: Ok @SirE_net4theDownvoter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to account for whether I was dealing with a student or a guest. I iterated over the $_POST variable and I parsed the key of the $_POST data to determine whether I was dealing with a student or a guest. Depending on that result I inserted the record in the attendance table using the value of the $_POST data to set the student_id or guest_id. Here is the code:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
      if($key[0]=="s" && $key[1]=="t"){//$_POST data is a student and not guest or submit

        //Submit record to attendance table using the $value as the student_id
      }
      if($key[0]=="g"){//$_POST data is a student and not guest or submit

        //Submit record to attendance table using the $value as the guest_id
      }       
    }
  }
?>
```